# How can I execute inline scripts in Boomla?

Tags: boomla

For simple prototyping, I would like to run inline scripts on the root of my website, which is an `html-1` file. The JavaScript console says:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://boomla.com self". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-fdu2bQSeIdU5fvNNkRCjiwUEOOb+NLZDyGNVShZ1vCM='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

I see that I can use the `.Trust` file to configure content security policies, but I didn't manage to set it up to enable inline scripts.

Comment: When I try copying the hash to the .Trust file as `script-src sha256-XTqNqFSUlZHAW7f/OGNYSOEzxKhjdAAGMXoid2VEbJk=`, it says `unsupported Content-Security-Policy directive value [sha256-XTqNqFSUlZHAW7f/OGNYSOEzxKhjdAAGMXoid2VEbJk=], supported forms are [foo.com], [http://foo.com], [sha256-...]`

Comment: apparently, the wrong base64 variant was implemented. Fix is on the way.

Comment: wrong base64 variant issue fixed in production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

Put your javascript code in a separate script file and link it from the root `html-1` content.

Files [types]

```
//example.com [html-1]
//example.com/script.js [static-1]
```

File contents for `//example.com`:

```
<script src="/script.js"></script>
hello world
```

File contents for `//example.com/script.js`

```
alert('Hello from script.js!')
```

## Use `<head>`

You can also use `<head>` in your `html-1` file to move the `<script>` to the response head:

```
<head>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
</head>
hello world
```

It is a feature of the `html-1` interpreter that you can use the `<head>` section, even when writing `.Inline` code. (In this example, the `.Request` method is executed, because the request is served directly.)

## Using `.Trust`

It was almost correct, but you have to quote the hash like this:

```
script-src 'sha256-XTqNqFSUlZHAW7f/OGNYSOEzxKhjdAAGMXoid2VEbJk='
```

**Note**: and then you will have to commit your changes to prevent malware from adding trusted parties. Thus, this approach is not convenient for hacking on your contents.